# dynamically hide or show TextView in ListView's rows corresponding to title's first character

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I need to hide or show label of the listView's row if the first character of the title matched the first time in the list. I attach picture that can help to understand clearly. 
[image]

I tried to do like this when I create an ArrayList of my contacts :

```
public ArrayList<ContactItem> getDisplayContacts(Context context)
    {   
        ArrayList<ContactItem> contactsList = null;
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
         try {
            Dao<ContactItem,Integer> daoSubject = db.getContactDao();
            contactsList = (ArrayList<ContactItem>) daoSubject.queryForAll();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {e.printStackTrace();}
         Collections.sort(contactsList, new Comparator<ContactItem>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ContactItem lhs, ContactItem rhs) {
                    return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
                }
            });
         for (int i =0; i< contactsList.size()-1;i++)
         {
             if (!contactsList.get(i).getName().substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(contactsList.get(i+1).getName().substring(0,1)))
                 contactsList.get(i).setContactLabel(true);
             else 
                 contactsList.get(i).setContactLabel(false);
         }
        return contactsList;

    }
```

but didn't get proper result. I also tried to put all the views in the custom ArrayAdapter and change after listView was created, but it also didn't help. To check title and show/hide label in the getView also didn't help. Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - remember all the positions where the 'letter-item' should be. For 'a' it would be most probably 0, for 'b' = number of 'a'-started names, for 'c' =  'b' postition + number of 'b'-started items and so on. Let this to be a SparseArray with String type.

When you got all of this, you should put all your data to SparseArray, where each item inex would be adjusted to previous calculation. For example, Alex - 1(0 is for 'a'-label,), Bob - 3(2 is for 'b'-label) and so on.

Then you write custom adapter and override method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

so, as if 'position' contains in the first array, you return 'label'-view with proper latter, otherwise, you get a common row item by accessing the second array.

English is not my native, so it might be hard to understand something - don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: thank you, very helpful answer. Should I create and fill SparseArray in the method of my ArrayList for adapter creation or directly in the Adapter class? Tried to implement both, but do not get proper result yet...

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi you can make this arrays in any place BEFORE you use the adapter. So, I suggest to make it after you have obtained the data(contacts as I can see). You make arrays, pass it, for example, as parameters in the adapter constructor and use it. I hope this clears what I said before.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my decision, maybe it helps to someone. So first of all I get an ArrayList of my ContactItem. 
Then I create my SparseArray container to give corresponding positions to the labels (call this method in the ListFragment before setting up the adapter):

```
 private SparseArray<String> adapterLabels(ArrayList<ContactItem> a)
      {
      labels = new SparseArray<String>(a.size());
      labels.append(0, a.get(0).getName().substring(0, 1));
         for(int i=1;i<a.size()-1;  i++)
         {

             if (!a.get(i).getName().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase(a.get(i-1).getName().substring(0, 1)))
                {

                    labels.append(i, a.get(i).getName().substring(0, 1));

                }
         }  
         return labels;
      }
```

And this is my adapter's constructor: 
        public ContactAdaper(Context context,  int layoutResourceId,List contacts, SparseArray labels) {
           super(context, layoutResourceId, contacts);
           this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
           this.context = context;

```
       this.contacts = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();
       this.contacts.addAll(contacts);
       this.labels = labels;


   }
```

and this is adapter's getView() method:

```
    @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       view = row;
       if(row == null)
       {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
           holder = new ContactHolder();
           holder.contact_label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contact_label);
           holder.contactIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactIcon);
           holder.contactName = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
           holder.contactNumber = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
           holder.contactDays = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactDays);
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       ContactItem contact = filtredContacts.get(position);
       try{
            if (contact.getContactGroup()!=null)
                holder.contactIcon.setBackgroundResource(contact.getContactGroup().getIcon());
               else
                holder.contactIcon.setBackgroundResource(contact.getIcon());


                holder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());
                holder.contactNumber.setText(contact.getNumber());
                holder.contactDays.setText(Integer.toString(contact.getDays()));
                if (labels.get(position)!=null)
                {
                    holder.contact_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.contact_label.setText(labels.get(position));
                }
                else
                        holder.contact_label.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();

       }

       return row;
   }
```